# IoC container mappings: singleton vs each-call creation

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependency-injection, ioc-container

Lets assume we have a very simple IConfiguration interface that responsible for returning a proper connection string

```
interface IConfiguration
{
   string ConnectionString {get;}
}
```

and lets assume only one instance of type that implemented such interface can be used (because it just returns a string, not manage a state, etc.)

So, there are, at least, two ways of how the interface could be registered within a container: as usual - new object per each type requesting, or as a singleton - one object for all type requests. Are there any differences between approaches (maybe performance reasons, lifetime management tricks, etc.)

```
container.For<IConfiguration>().Use<ConfigurationImpl>();
```

vs

```
container.For<IConfiguration>().Singleton().Use<ConfigurationImpl>();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Object lifetime management using DI container usually boils down to:

1. Singleton scoped (sometimes container scoped)
2. Transient (per request from container)
3. Per graph(context) (example: presenter/controller in desktop applications, session in web applications/web servers)

I urge you to read Mark Seemanns excelent book [Dependency Injection in .Net.](https://www.manning.com/books/dependency-injection-in-dot-net) It has special chapter dedicated to object lifetime management.

In general you're thread-safe with transients and singleton is good for performance reasons or state sharing. You also must make careful note of how your resources are being disposed.

If you have a framework the implies some design you can use parts of this framework as a context for lifetime of the instance.

Example: you have 2 dbcommands used by asp mvc controller so you can share dbsession between them by making dbsession lifetime tied to the controller lifetime.

There are more ways to manage object lifetime - like pooled, lazy loaded or futures, but they're quite less used than the first 3. Read on Mark Seemann for that.